# Writing .csv files from C++

Tags: c++, csv

I'm trying to output some data to a .csv file and it is outputting it to the file but it isn't separating the data into different columns and seems to be outputting the data incorrectly.

```
    ofstream Morison_File ("linear_wave_loading.csv");         //Opening file to print info to
    Morison_File << "Time Force(N/m)" << endl;          //Headings for file
    for (t = 0; t <= 20; t++) {
      u = sin(omega * t);
      du = cos(omega * t); 
      F = (0.5 * rho * C_d * D * u * fabs(u)) + rho * Area * C_m * du; 

      cout << "t = " << t << "\t\tF = " << F << endl;
      Morison_File << t;                                 //Printing to file
      Morison_File << F;

    }

     Morison_File.close();
```

Time and Force(N/m) are in columns A and B respectively but the t and F values are both printing the first row.

What is the syntax to separate them to print t into column A and F into column B?

Comment: You could use separator characters such as `;` which is usually supported by spreadsheets editors instead of tabulation

Comment: The "S" in "CSV" stands for "Separated". You do not write any separator. Not between the values, and not at the end of the record.

Comment: by the way, the header itself does not separate Time and Force by a tabulation

Comment: I did have commas between them before but that didn't work either. To separate t and F there's just one space between them, two spaces separates them by two columns.

Comment: @remi the ; didn't work between them either...

Comment: Incidentally, the "C" in "CSV" usually stands for "Comma", even though the separator doesn't actually matter. If you want each value you write to be formatted (e.g. left justified with a specific field width) then read about [I/O manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip).

Comment: If that's not what you want, you need to ***show us*** what the output should look like.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I did this before in C and I used the command: fprintf(filename, "%lf,%lf\n", theta, theta_rad);

This printed the theta values in column A and theta_rad values in column B. That's all I want on this, all t values should print in column A and all F values should print in column B.

Comment: Then read my first comment again. You need *two* separators, first between `t` and `F` (the comma), then one (usually a newline) to separate each record. your C++ code is not equivalent to the C code because in the C code you *do* write the separators but you don't in the C++ code.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ok i worked it out! I didn't quite get what you meant but I think I did what you were saying anyway, here's how I did it: 
Morison_File << t << " " <<F << endl;

Answer (score 114):

There is nothing special about a CSV file. You can create them using a text editor by simply following the [basic rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules_and_examples). The RFC 4180 *(tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180)* accepted separator is the comma ',' not the semi-colon ';'. Programs like MS Excel expect a comma as a separator.

There are some programs that treat the comma as a decimal and the semi-colon as a separator, but these are technically outside of the "accepted" standard for CSV formatted files.

So, when creating a CSV you create your filestream and add your lines like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
      std::ofstream myfile;
      myfile.open ("example.csv");
      myfile << "This is the first cell in the first column.\n";
      myfile << "a,b,c,\n";
      myfile << "c,s,v,\n";
      myfile << "1,2,3.456\n";
      myfile << "semi;colon";
      myfile.close();
      return 0;
}
```

This will result in a CSV file that looks like this when opened in MS Excel:

[image: Image of CSV file created with C++]

Comment: MS Excel will interpret CSV files differently depending on the user's region settings. A 'European' Excel expects semi-colon separated fields (and uses the comma as decimal point).

Comment: My Excel expects semi-colon, but my Libre Office just gives me a bunch of oriental characters. Do you know why?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Libre Office but according to their website you might need to set the column delimiter when importing a csv. Instructions are here: https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Importing_and_Exporting_CSV_Files

Comment: You forgot to escape values that contain separators.

Comment: I was getting an access violation error on the close() call using the code above.  But this worked for me: `std::fstream myFile; myfile.open ("example.csv", std::ios::out | std::ios::app);`

Answer (score 15):

Here is a STL-like class

File "csvfile.h"

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class csvfile;

inline static csvfile& endrow(csvfile& file);
inline static csvfile& flush(csvfile& file);

class csvfile
{
    std::ofstream fs_;
    const std::string separator_;
public:
    csvfile(const std::string filename, const std::string separator = ";")
        : fs_()
        , separator_(separator)
    {
        fs_.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);
        fs_.open(filename);
    }

    ~csvfile()
    {
        flush();
        fs_.close();
    }

    void flush()
    {
        fs_.flush();
    }

    void endrow()
    {
        fs_ << std::endl;
    }

    csvfile& operator << ( csvfile& (* val)(csvfile&))
    {
        return val(*this);
    }

    csvfile& operator << (const char * val)
    {
        fs_ << '"' << val << '"' << separator_;
        return *this;
    }

    csvfile& operator << (const std::string & val)
    {
        fs_ << '"' << val << '"' << separator_;
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T>
    csvfile& operator << (const T& val)
    {
        fs_ << val << separator_;
        return *this;
    }
};


inline static csvfile& endrow(csvfile& file)
{
    file.endrow();
    return file;
}

inline static csvfile& flush(csvfile& file)
{
    file.flush();
    return file;
}
```

File "main.cpp"

```
#include "csvfile.h"

int main()
{
    try
    {
        csvfile csv("MyTable.csv"); // throws exceptions!
        // Header
        csv << "X" << "VALUE"        << endrow;
        // Data
        csv <<  1  << "String value" << endrow;
        csv <<  2  << 123            << endrow;
        csv <<  3  << 1.f            << endrow;
        csv <<  4  << 1.2            << endrow;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception was thrown: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Latest version [here](https://gist.github.com/rudolfovich/f250900f1a833e715260a66c87369d15)

Comment: this csv-writer class would help even more if it would take an open `std::ostream` to work on, think of `std::stringbuf`

Comment: I'm curious about this pattern where you have overloaded the `<<` operator to take a function pointer that returns an instance of the same class... What does that do?

Comment: @rocksNwaves, this overload for the `endrow` and `flush` calls. So you can write ` << endrow;` in the end, in std c++ library it's done differently., But this approach also works. As you can see it just calls the function passed as an argument so you can implement your own helper functions if needed. I would use custom structures now perhaps.

Answer (score 8):

Change

```
Morison_File << t;                                 //Printing to file
Morison_File << F;
```

To

```
Morison_File << t << ";" << F << endl;                                 //Printing to file
```

a , would also do instead of ;

Answer (score 4):

You must ";" separator, CSV => Comma Separator Value

```
 ofstream Morison_File ("linear_wave_loading.csv");         //Opening file to print info to
    Morison_File << "'Time'; 'Force(N/m)' " << endl;          //Headings for file
    for (t = 0; t <= 20; t++) {
      u = sin(omega * t);
      du = cos(omega * t); 
      F = (0.5 * rho * C_d * D * u * fabs(u)) + rho * Area * C_m * du; 

      cout << "t = " << t << "\t\tF = " << F << endl;
      Morison_File << t << ";" << F;

    }

     Morison_File.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wirte to a .csv file in C++ - you should use the syntax of :

```
myfile <<" %s; %s; %d", string1, string2, double1 <<endl;
```

This will write the three variables (string 1&2 and double1) into separate columns and leave an empty row below them. In excel the ; means the new row, so if you want to just take a new row - you can alos write a simple ";" before writing your new data into the file. If you don't want to have an empty row below - you should delete the endl and use the:

```
myfile.open("result.csv", std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
```

syntax when opening the .csv file (example the result.csv). In this way next time you write something into your result.csv file - it will write it into a new row directly below the last one - so you can easily manage a for cycle if you would like to.

Comment: I doubt that `myfile <<" %s; %s; %d", string1, string2, double1 <<endl;` will work. What version od C++ should it be?

Answer (score 0):

As explained above by @kris, depending on the region configurations of MS Excel it won't interpret the comma as the separator character. In my case I had to change it to semi-colon

Comment: An example might be useful. @user3460758 commented that semi-colons did not work for him. There should not be any problem with commas unless one or more of the values has a comma, and then it is generally better to put quotes around values with commas, eg. 5,"2,000",12

Comment: As I said, this an Excel Region configuration problem, as mentioned before. Don't see how I can produce and example from this statement.